# Percentiles assertion in Rust Goose

Tags: rust, goose

I'm using Rust `goose` for performance test, and also an external lib called `goose-egg` to allow me to get some validation from the response.

```
async fn hello_endpoint(user: &mut GooseUser) -> TransactionResult {
    let goose = user.get("/hello").await?;
    let validate = &Validate::builder()
        .status(200)
        .text("we will implement /world")
        .build();
    validate_and_load_static_assets(user, goose, &validate).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

What I found a limitation so far, coming from Scala Gatling, is that it seems in `goose` we cannot assert on the median, and percentiles for the response time.

Something that if you ask me is the most important part to have an automated performance test, since it is the only way to keep the SLA in a simulation.

Am I missing something here, or is the only thing we can measure the status code response?

Comment: Although I've never had to in Rust, can you set an execution time limit for the tests themselves and leave it at that? I know you can do this trivially with things like [mocha](https://mochajs.org) for Node where too slow is an automatic fail if configured that way.